How to hide the internal link button that opens customer from within quotations by clicking on the internal link in Odoo without coding solutions?
The arrow button shown in the image
I would like to hide the internal link button (the arrow button) to open the customer from the quotation
I tried with access rights but i am not able to find the correct way to hide the internal link button

The field attribute options='{"no_open": True}' is used to prevent the opening the record using internal link. It is used inside the field like in the example give below.
<field name="sale_order_id" options='{"no_open": True}'/>

